# course index.php file it's not loading after upgraded from moodle 2.2.11

Tags: php, upgrade, moodle

I need some help with my course material created for moodle. The problem is that after I upgraded the 2.2.11 moodle version to version 2.8.3 , the course main index.php file it's not interpreted anymore and it shows the source of that index.php file. Also with the upgrading process I switched to a new php 5.6.3 version(The new moodle it works only with 5.4 or higher versions, and I think this is the problem, because with the 5.3 php version it worked everything fine) upgrade.The error is :that when I try to acces the course, instead of the course material place it appears the index.php source code.

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP code is not executing and instead is loading as plaintext, then I'm 80% sure this is a problem with PHP rather than Moodle itself.

First thing you need to do is check that PHP is installed and running.

You can do this by running this code:

```
<?    phpinfo();    ?>
```

If you get a return, then it's working, if not, then revisit your cPanel and have a gander at your settings.

Check that your Apache server is running PHP by checking your httpd.conf file.

And I know it sounds daft, but also check your index.php file's syntax. (Especially if PHP turns out to be running fine) because that would generally mean that you have a syntax error. If it boils down to this, check that all your  statements, otherwise the server will just assume it's plaintext. Easiest way to do this is using NotePad++. Click on any

**Tldr: This is probably PHP not running correctly. Nothing to do with Moodle I imagine. But I could be wrong.**

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The <?    phpinfo();    ?> code works , the php file it works with the php 5.3 version ... the code is here :  <?php
   session_start();
  ......
      $_SESSION['tagloaderEncrypt'] = $encryption;
   };
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV=CONTENT-TYPE CONTENT='text/html; <body> charset=utf-8' />.......</body></html>

Comment: I think is related with my VPS settings , I have  parralels VPS and I have the PHP settings:   PHP support : Run PHP as : CGI module , PHP version: 5.6.3 . And maybe I should set up as Apache module ? But I dont know how , because I only have the php version 5.3 for the apache module.

Comment: Hey dude. You **need** PHP 5.4.4 or higher running on your Apache for Moodle 2.8 to function.

Comment: The moodle 2.8 is already running correctly, because I was able to set up for the specific website(domain) the correct php version( 5.6.3). But the problem is that the specific course contents which were build earlier for the older moodle version , now they don't load.

Comment: The last comment is a different question I think - did you copy the sitedata folder from the old site?

Comment: Yes, I did copy the sitedata, the other sourse contents are working fine, but they have another format. Only this content type have the main file an index.php which is triggering the course content.

Comment: Solved!  After a made another sitedata copy and uploaded again, everything worked fine. Thanks

Comment: hi - where does one type in the code: <?    phpinfo();    ?>  to see if php is working? i tried the terminal, but i don't think it's that. any ideas?  [Edit: is this the answer: https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/php/how-to-check-php-installed-detect-php-version.html ]